# Dropping Wifi: "Wifi doesn't have a valid IP configuration."

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I'm on a Lenovo laptop running Win 10.

A couple of days ago my computer started dropping off the wifi. And not it won't connect. I get get "no internet, secured" when I click on the wifi button. And when I run troubleshooter I get wifi didn't have a valid IP configuration What makes it weirder. Is sometimes it will connect to the web. But if I open a new tab the signal goes down. Other times, it will stay connected for a while and then just drop. I can eventually get it back on by disconnecting and reconnecting 5-6 times. This morning it just wouldn't connect for like 4 hours.

I've looked up a bunch of help articles and none of them have done the trick. Of note: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhhXH.jpg)

````
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipconfig /release

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 10 while it has its media disconnected. No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 11 while it has its media disconnected. No operation can be performed on Bluetooth Network Connection while it has its media disconnected.

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd9b:6269:8326:1:5825:63af:5b59:a00b Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fd9b:6269:8326:1:d51c:6d5f:ba53:58eb Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5825:63af:5b59:a00b%7 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::625f:8dff:fe77:2972%7

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>```
````

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your router?  It may be a DHCP related problem (ie giving your computer an IP address - which is done by your router).  Maybe your router has too many devices trying to connect to it - I expect that if you don't have problems when connecting to other WIFI routers the issue is with your router.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm on a Lenovo laptop running Win 10.
>
> A couple of days ago my computer started dropping off the wifi. And
> not it won't connect. I get get "no internet, secured" when I click on
> the wifi button. And when I run troubleshooter I get wifi didn't have
> a valid IP configuration

There are two things for you to review and check: (B) Your Wireless Driver / TCP/IP and (A) your Router. Both can cause issues.

**(A)** You might first reset your Router. That may help, but at least you know if not.

**(B)** Run the Lenovo Driver Update (normally in Control Panel) and update all drivers, especially the Wireless Driver.

For sure, upgrade or at least reinstall the Wireless driver.  Reinstalling Wireless driver will do a full TCP/IP Reset, so this is the best first step.

Comment: why do you think this could be a wireless driver issue when the message is "no internet, secured".  To me this implies the network driver is working fine, but there is a problem assigning an IP address, gateway or DNS server - ie above the Network Access/Link layer.

Comment: Reinstalling Wireless   resets TCP/IP so 2 birds with one stone. I also reset the Router and added that.

Comment: It might be worth doing it the other way round - ie router reboot first - if the problem is with the router it will likely recur, and it would be good to know where the problem lies for next time!

Comment: You make a valid point and I re-ordered my post. Thank you.

Comment: @Yotebeth - Any update?